# How to REQUEST_METADATA from Square?

Tags: square, square-connect

I'm making a call to Square using web api Android. The response of the transaction gives me `CLIENT_TRANSACTION_ID`. I want to know other information like transaction amount and the change as well as I can see in receipt email. I can't see how to give `S.com.squareup.register.REQUEST_METADATA` a value  while firing an intent so that i can have `S.com.squareup.register.RESULT_REQUEST_METADATA` in response. Also what are the optional values we can give to square api against this key. The code is below

`<a href="intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.register.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.browser_fallback_url=https://2f857915.ngrok.io/square_callback;S.com.squareup.register.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=https://2f857915.ngrok.io/square_callback;S.com.squareup.register.CLIENT_ID=sq0idp-6Lo2W9zX8K9b08zKxmfUtw;S.com.squareup.register.API_VERSION=v1.3;i.com.squareup.register.TOTAL_AMOUNT=100;S.com.squareup.register.CURRENCY_CODE=USD;S.com.squareup.register.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.register.TENDER_CARD,com.squareup.register.TENDER_CARD_ON_FILE,com.squareup.register.TENDER_CASH,com.squareup.register.TENDER_OTHER;end;">Charge With Square</a>`

I want to have information about this payment so that can be used in my application. For example payment done, payment currency, taxes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the [Retrieve Transaction](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-retrievetransaction) endpoint to turn that ID into additional information. Note, you should only get `CLIENT_TRANSACTION_ID` if you do not process a card, and if you process a card payment, you should get back a `SERVER_TRANSACTION_ID`

Comment: Oh okay! Thank you very much for your response :)

I got it. But when i tried it, it generates Not Found api error.
I used this `CLIENT_TRANSACTION_ID` as `TRANSACTION_ID` to retrieve a transaction for a specific location and it generates Not FOUND api exception. I'm working in ruby. 

I listed all the transactions for a specific location, but none of the `@client_id` or `@transaction_id` matches to the CLIENT_TRANSACTION_ID i got in params.

Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: You must be not be processing a card payment. If you just have a `CLIENT_TRANSACTION_ID` then you should use the List [Transactions endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-listtransactions) and compare the `client_id` to your `CLIENT_TRANSACTION_ID` to see which ones match up.

Comment: You are right! i'm trying simply a cash payment that's why i'm getting only `CLIENT_TRANSACTION_ID` in response. FYI i was using the same end point to retrieve all the transactions and was matching the `client_id` to my `CLIENT_TRANSACTION_ID`. That's exactly what i was saying; how is it possible that none of my `CLIENT_TRANSACTION_ID` matches any of the `client_id` of transactions i retrieved :(

I'm not getting where am i doing wrong :(

Comment: Would this be any issue that while firing intent i'm specifying `S.com.squareup.register.API_VERSION=v1.3` but the API calls i'm using is of version 2?
I tried many times, but my `CLIENT_TRANSACTION_ID` doesn't match any of `client_id` of transactions i retrieved.

Comment: I tried one more thing. May be this will help in troubleshooting. I copied `CLIENT_TRANSACTION_ID` and initiated another cash transaction. This time i listed all the transactions, i couldn't find either transaction, neither previous(the one i copied) nor the recent one. 

Please note that (may be this will be issue) intent i fired was for version 1.3 and api calls i'm using points to version 2.

Waiting for your response  :)
thanks

Comment: Could you email me at the address in my profile? In that email if you could include the email address you used for your account and your `location_id`. I can check our logs and see what is up.

Comment: Thank you @tristansokol the issue has been resolved. It was my bad, i was trying to retrieve transactions with different location_id. Thank you very much for your patience and quick response :)